# How to view remote desktop logins?

Tags: security

I manage a lot of lab machines. I want to see the last time that somebody logged in with Remote Desktop. I will give a system to somebody for use, and they don't use it for 60+ days and it sits idle. I want to see the last time (or a list of) all logins via remote desktop to the system.

Checked event viewer and it shows all kinds of logons from other machines as automated services scan them. Not sure how to filter them to just remote desktop.

Answer (score 2):

In the event viewer, try to find records with "Logon Type 10". It represents remote login events.

[Find more information about Logon Types in this article.](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/misc_network_security/Logon-Types.html)